# Quais são as variáveis para plugin cordova de geolocalização no iOS?

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Durante a criação de um plugin para Cordova que utiliza geolocalização, é necessário adicionar uma variável para "privacy - Location Usage Description" que é a `GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION`.

no config eu tenho:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git">
    <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de Uso"/>
</plugin>
```

mas quais são as variáveis para as "privacy - Location Always Usage Description" e "privacy - Location When in Use Description"?

assim, na config do xocde, as três mensagens no info.plist seriam preenchidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variáveis para as demais opções de geolocalização do iOS são

```
<variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de uso" />
<variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_AND_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de uso" />
<variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de uso" />
<variable name="LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de uso" />
<variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Mensagem de uso" />
```

Basta adicionar estas variaveis no plugin de geolocation.

Assim todas as infos serão preenchidas no momento que compilar o app com o cordova.